# Set TextMessageEncoding-message version in wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding

I am trying to call SOAP1.2 service using wsHttpBinding. The service accepts rejects the default *Soap12WSAddressing10* message version. It only accepts *SOAP12*.

One suggestion I could get from the Internet search was to create the TextMessageEncodingElement in a custom binding.

How can it be either be accomplished  using code or configuration ?

```
WSHttpBinding myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();   
myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;            
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = 
HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
//MessageVersion = SOAP12
```

On using the custom wsBinding  as well, there is no suggested placeholder to specify the message version.

```
<wsHttpBinding>       
<binding name="customWS">          
<security mode="Transport">
<message clientCredentialType="Certificate"></message>            
</security>          
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 2):

Soap12 specify the soapaction by content-type header. I think it is not implemented in net core. I use the following code.

`var encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None), Encoding.UTF8);`

But this is not implemented in net core.

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
SoapTools.CustomEncodingBindingElement customEncodingBindingElement = new SoapTools.CustomEncodingBindingElement();
customEncodingBindingElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12,AddressingVersion.None);
```